# Create color histogram of an image using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a neat way to compute a color histogram of an image? Maybe by abusing the internal code of `tf.histogram_summary`? From what I've seen, this code is not very modular and calls directly some C++ code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to use the histogram in later TF computation, or is outputting the histogram the end goal?

Comment: @dga I'm using it in later TF computation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use [`tf.unsorted_segment_sum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#unsorted_segment_sum), where the "segment IDs" are computed from the color values and the thing you sum is a `tf.ones` vector.  Note that `tf.unsorted_segment_sum` is probably better thought of as "bucket sum".  It implements `dest[segment] += thing_to_sum` -- exactly the operation you need for a histogram.

In slightly pseudocode (meaning I haven't run this):

```
binned_values = tf.reshape(tf.floor(img_r * (NUM_BINS-1)), [-1])
binned_values = tf.cast(binned_values, tf.int32)
ones = tf.ones_like(binned_values, dtype=tf.int32)
counts = tf.unsorted_segment_sum(ones, binned_values, NUM_BINS)
```

You could accomplish this in one pass instead of separating out the r, g, and b values with a split if you wanted to cleverly construct your "ones" to look like "100100..." for red, "010010" for green, etc., but I suspect it would be slower overall, and harder to read.  I'd just do the split that you proposed above.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I'm using right now:

```py
# Assumption: img is a tensor of the size [img_width, img_height, 3], normalized to the range [-1, 1].
with tf.variable_scope('color_hist_producer') as scope:
  bin_size = 0.2
  hist_entries = []
  # Split image into single channels
  img_r, img_g, img_b = tf.split(2, 3, img)
  for img_chan in [img_r, img_g, img_b]:
    for idx, i in enumerate(np.arange(-1, 1, bin_size)):
      gt = tf.greater(img_chan, i)
      leq = tf.less_equal(img_chan, i + bin_size)
      # Put together with logical_and, cast to float and sum up entries -> gives count for current bin.
      hist_entries.append(tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.logical_and(gt, leq), tf.float32)))

  # Pack scalars together to a tensor, then normalize histogram.
  hist = tf.nn.l2_normalize(tf.pack(hist_entries), 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tf.histogram_fixed_width
```

might be what you are looking for...

Full documentation on

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/histogram_fixed_width